# How to make auto layout for uiview inside uitableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

i'm working for universal app; i've two uiView (top View and bottom View) top view with imageView and bottom View with uitableView; i make constrains for this tableView and the label inside the cell; but the problem on iPad; as shown on the following images
[image: first screen shoot]

so when i put constrains for uiLbael to be at the center of the cell it's the center at all devices except iPad

[image: these my constrains]

the problem here for iPad uiLabel not on the center
[image]

Comment: it's already checked for both use auto layout and use size classes

Comment: I mean active size class which you can adjust at the bottom of IB window. To apply constraint to all devices and orientation it should be wAny hAny

Comment: i worked for wAny hAny

Comment: It can be an IB bug - try to clear constraints, restart Xcode and add constraints again.

Comment: I make restart for Xcode but the problem still

Comment: Did you try to run it on actual device or simulator?

Comment: Yes; it's working perfect on iPhone but on iPad same problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that label has the constraint horizontally centered in container? I cannot tell from your screen shot. I see the guide lines, but this does not necessarily meant the constraint is set.  Select horizontal centered in container from the align menu. If that doesn't work I'd suggest keeping the constraints and changing your size class to the iPad (Regular/Regular) and adding the constraint.

Comment: I already put the horizontal and vertical centered in container